# AVPlayer Swift: How do I hide controls and disable landscape view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

since this is my first post, just a few words about me: Usually I design stuff (UI primarily) but I really wanted to take a leap into programming to understand you guys better. So I decided build a small app to get going.

So I've been trying to figure this out for hours now – this is my first app project ever so I apologise for my newbyness.

All I want to do is to hide the controls of AVPlayer and disable landscape view but I just can't figure out where to put `showsPlaybackControls = false`.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    private var firstAppear = true

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if firstAppear {
            do {
                try playVideo()
                firstAppear = false
            } catch AppError.InvalidResource(let name, let type) {
                debugPrint("Could not find resource \(name).\(type)")
            } catch {
                debugPrint("Generic error")
            }

        }
    }

    private func playVideo() throws {
        guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4") else {
            throw AppError.InvalidResource("video", "m4v")
        }
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
        self.presentViewController(playerController, animated: false) {
            player.play()
        }
    }
}

enum AppError : ErrorType {
    case InvalidResource(String, String)
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`showsPlaybackControls` is a property of `AVPlayerViewController`, so you can set it after you create it:

```
playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
```

If you want to allow only landscape, you can subclass `AVPlayerViewController`, override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and return only landscape, then use that class instead of `AVPlayerViewController`.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, if you go to the documentation for `AVPlayerViewController` you'll find a warning that says:

> Do not subclass AVPlayerViewController. Overriding this class’s methods is unsupported and results in undefined behavior.

They probably don't want you to override playback-related methods that could interfere with the behavior, and I would say that overriding *only* `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is safe.

**However**, if you want an alternative solution, you can create your own view controller class that overrides `supportedInterfaceOrientations` to return landscape only, and place the `AVPlayerViewController` inside that view controller.

Comment: While this may work fine, just keep in mind that subclassing AVPlayerViewController is not recommended or supported, per the apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller

Comment: @taykay08 thanks for the heads up, I updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Hi, good answer however, in mi case when i press the button "Done" from the AVPlayerController and come back to the initial "ViewController" change to landscape when is only "Portrait".
Posdata: I use a PresentViewController to go to ViewController that contain the AVPlayerController

Any idea the why and how solve it