# Xamarin iOS: How to hide seek bar in AvPlayer?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm building an app in xamarin ios using AvPlayer. How can I hide the seek bar ?

```
_playerViewController = new CustomAVPlayerViewController();
_player = new AVPlayer();
_playerViewController.Player = _player;
SetNativeControl(_playerViewController.View);


public class CustomAVPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController
    {
        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875659/avplayer-swift-how-do-i-hide-controls-and-disable-landscape-view/37875740 ?

Comment: Thanks @G.hakim I just want to hide only seek bar( or disable seek bar), but the sample as you've provided hide all :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show the controls or want to highly customize the appearance, I recommend you to use `AVPlayerLayer`:

```
public class CustomPlayerRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomPlayer, UIView>
{

    AVPlayer _player;
    AVPlayerLayer _playerLayer;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomPlayer1> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            _player = new AVPlayer(new NSUrl(NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("sample.mp4", null), false));
            _playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.FromPlayer(_player);

            UIView view = new UIView();
            view.Layer.AddSublayer(_playerLayer);

            SetNativeControl(view);

            //_player.Play();
            // Add custom controls as you want on this view
        }
    }

    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);

        _playerLayer.Frame = rect;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Land Lu - I know but when were are using AVPlayerLayer, we have to reimplement all other features for full screen, pause, replay... Is there a other way to hide only seek bar or do not allow user to interact with seek bar ?

Comment: @PhamThai You can't hide the specified control on AVPlayer View Controller. You have to customize it depending on your own requirement.